# nginx-rtmp on_publish not working throws error could not access specified channel or stream key on OBS

Tags: nginx, rtmp

nginx-rtmp makes OBS throw error makes obs throw error saying could not access specified channel or stream key once i add an on_publish event to my nginx file any help will greatly be appreciated:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        on_publish http://ip_address/api/user/login;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the problem was because on_publish expects a response and the endpoint had a bug on it

Comment: Can you please give me some more information on this? In my case the on_publish is not reaching to the endpoint. To be specific, got 499 error code.